# Training error loss vs "classification loss"

Tags: machine-learning, overfitting, interpolation

From the paper [To understand deep learning we need to understand kernel learning](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.01396), three questions:

In section 2 "Setup" there appears a definition of *interpolated classifier* as an algo that has zero or close to zero training error and *overfitted* as an algo "if the same holds for classification loss".

Question 1: what is the mathematical definition of these two classifiers? If an interpolated classifier only depends on the training data, then an overfitted algo in this context could mean an algo that has zero or near zero *test* error (i.e. generalization error)...which seems different than more traditional definitions of "overfit".

Question 2. The authors then go on to state that in their definitions an interpolated classifier is necessarily an overfit classifier -- why?

Question 3. In section 4, does the *t-overfits the data* definition depend on a fixed training set? I.e. do they mean t-overfit a *fixed* but arbitrary training dataset?

Answer (score 1):

The question does not quite accurately represent the definition given in the paper:

> Interpolation versus “overfitting”. In this paper we will refer to
> classifiers as interpolated if their square loss on the training error
> is zero or close to zero. We will call classifiers overfitted if the
> same holds for classification loss (for the theoretical bounds we will
> additionally require a small fixed margin on the training data).
> Notice that while interpolation implies overfitting, the converse does
> not hold.

From the question:

"if interpolated classifier as an algo that has zero or close to zero training error and overfitted as an algo "if the same holds for classification loss"."

Note that the paper says "squared loss" rather than "training error", so it is regarding interpolation as if the model is a regression model, predicting the numeric value of the target.  However the paper is really about classification, so it is re-using the term "overfitting" to make a distinction between treating the output as a regression (square loss) and a classification (classification loss/error rate).

> Question 1: what is the mathematical definition of these two types of
> classifiers?

There isn't two types of classifier, I think it is just two different interpretations of the output.

> If an interpolated classifier only depends on the training data, then
> an overfitted algo in this context could mean an algo that has zero or
> near zero test error (i.e. generalization error)...which seems
> different than more traditional definitions of "overfit".

No, they are both talking about the error on the training set.  If the model interpolates, then it's output is numerically close to the the target value.  However, you don't need to be very close to the target value to get the classification right as the "score" is thresholded to make the classification.

> Question 2. The authors then go on to state that in their definitions
> an interpolated classifier is necessarily an overfit classifier --
> why?

If a model interpolates, then the numeric difference between the prediction and target will be much smaller than the difference between the target and the classification threshold, so any interpolated point will be correctly classified.  If the model correctly classifies all patterns in the training set then it is defined as being "overfitted".  This doesn't apply the other way round, the model predictions can be *just* the right side of the threshold for all training patterns, in which case it is overfitted (by their definition) but it doesn't interpolate (as there is a substantial error on the prediction of the label when viewed as a regression).

I would define overfitting as meaning reducing the training loss (which measures the "fit" of the model to the data) so much that generalisation performance (e.g. test/validation set) becomes worse.  Arguably while the generalisation performance is improving you haven't fitted the model *too* closely as fitting it closer still improves generalisation performance.

However, I can see the logic in their usage.  If you had a perfect Bayes optimal classifier, it would give a non-zero classification error on the training sample as well, so you could argue that the model is overfit because there exists a better model with better generalisation performance but worse training set performance.  However, however, it is not necessarily the case that the Bayes optimal classifier is realisable by the current model architecture or can actually be found by the training algorithm, so in practice the best model may be achievable with zero training set error and we have benign "overfitting".

It is best not to get too focussed on terminology - sometimes a sub-field will be using their own definitions/meanings of terms and we just have to learn their jargon.

> Question 3. In section 4, does the t-overfits the data definition
> depend on a fixed training set? I.e. do they mean t-overfit a fixed
> but arbitrary training dataset?

Yes, I think that is correct - that is fairly standard for analysis of generalisation bounds.

Comment: PPS - in terms of definitions of these 'classifiers', would also be great to see how your answer mathematically differs or improves upon the one I proposed below

Comment: @Quetzalcoatl I am not sure what kind of definition you are seeking other than that I have given.  A classifier that interpolates is one with a small least-squares error, and overfitted classifier (in the sense of the paper) is one that assigns all of the training instances to the correct class.  They are not *types* of classifiers, they are properties of a classifier.  The squared loss (L2) is just the loss minimised in least-squares regression, what do you mean by "numerically differ"?

Comment: thank you. In supervised classification, is there a definition of "squared error loss"?

Comment: @Quetzalcoatl the definition of squared error loss is the same as that for least-squares regression.  This is completely standard, for instance Fisher's Linear Discriminant Analysis (LDA) is equivalent to least-squares regression on the class labels.  The Least Squares Support Vector Machine is a nice non-linear classifier that uses the squared loss.  However, I think you may be missing the point, I don't think the paper requires that the classifier is trained using the squared loss, it is just saying that for an interpolating classifier, the output is numerically very similar to the target.

Comment: @Quetzalcoatl sorry, if you are at a mathematical level where you understand the paper you ought to be able to cast that into whatever mathematical notation suits you for yourself.  It is unreasonable to expect me to spend time on mathematical notation that is not necessary to understand the answers to the question.  Asking for them suggests this is a homework question.

Comment: Well the original question asked for mathematical definitions, but your inputs are definitely appreciated. thank you

Comment: Someone flagged this post as low-quality. For future purpose, please use the flag more wisely and carefully. And before flagging, you might try to communicate with the answerer.